# SQL: How do I group by a unique combination of two columns?

Tags: mysql, sql, heidisql

Context:

- A table `message` has the columns `from_user_id` and `to_user_id`
- The user should see the recent conversations with the last message displayed
- A conversation consists of multiple messages, that have the same combination of user IDs (user sends messages, user receives messages)

Table content:

```
+-------------------------------------------------+--------------+------------+
| text                                            | from_user_id | to_user_id |
+-------------------------------------------------+--------------+------------+
| Hi there!                                       |           13 |         14 | <- Liara to Penelope
| Oh hi, how are you?                             |           14 |         13 | <- Penelope to Liara
| Fine, thanks for asking. How are you?           |           13 |         14 | <- Liara to Penelope
| Could not be better! How are things over there? |           14 |         13 | <- Penelope to Liara
| Hi, I just spoke to Penelope!                   |           13 |         15 | <- Liara to Zara
| Oh you did? How is she?                         |           15 |         13 | <- Zara to Liara
| Liara told me you guys texted, how are things?  |           15 |         14 | <- Zara to Penelope
| Fine, she's good, too                           |           14 |         15 | <- Penelope to Zara
+-------------------------------------------------+--------------+------------+
```

My attempt was to group by `from_user_id` and `to_user_id`, but I obviously get a group of the messages received by the user and another group of messages send by the user.

```
SELECT text, from_user_id, to_user_id,created FROM message 
WHERE from_user_id=13 or to_user_id=13
GROUP BY from_user_id, to_user_id
ORDER BY created DESC
```

Gets me:

```
+-------------------------------+--------------+------------+---------------------+
| text                          | from_user_id | to_user_id | created             |
+-------------------------------+--------------+------------+---------------------+
| Oh you did? How is she?       |           15 |         13 | 2017-09-01 21:45:14 | <- received by Liara
| Hi, I just spoke to Penelope! |           13 |         15 | 2017-09-01 21:44:51 | <- send by Liara
| Oh hi, how are you?           |           14 |         13 | 2017-09-01 17:06:53 |
| Hi there!                     |           13 |         14 | 2017-09-01 17:06:29 |
+-------------------------------+--------------+------------+---------------------+
```

Although I want:

```
+-------------------------------+--------------+------------+---------------------+
| text                          | from_user_id | to_user_id | created             |
+-------------------------------+--------------+------------+---------------------+
| Oh you did? How is she?       |           15 |         13 | 2017-09-01 21:45:14 | <- Last message of conversation with Zara
| Oh hi, how are you?           |           14 |         13 | 2017-09-01 17:06:53 |
+-------------------------------+--------------+------------+---------------------+
```

How can I achieve that?

EDIT:
Using `least` or `greatest` does not lead to the required results either.
It does group the entries correctly, but as you can see in the result, the last message is incorrect.

```
+----+-------------------------------------------------+------+---------------------+--------------+------------+
| id | text                                            | read | created             | from_user_id | to_user_id |
+----+-------------------------------------------------+------+---------------------+--------------+------------+
|  8 | Oh you did? How is she?                         | No   | 2017-09-01 21:45:14 |           15 |         13 |
|  5 | Could not be better! How are things over there? | No   | 2017-09-01 17:07:47 |           14 |         13 |
+----+-------------------------------------------------+------+---------------------+--------------+------------+
```

Comment: Can we apply least to to_user_id and greatest to from_user_id and then group them

Comment: Already tried, I edited the attempt to the question. Grouping works correct, but I don't get the last message

Comment: Why there isnt `14, 15` message in the final result?

Comment: Those are intentional wrong columns, I only want one users messages:
`WHERE from_user_id=13 or to_user_id=13`

Comment: So for user 13 you want all conversation partners (14 and 15) with the latest post? No matter whether #13 was the sender or the receiver? I understand why it is "Oh you did? How is she?" for #15. But why is it not "Could not be better! How are things over there?" for #14?

Comment: You're right about that @Thorsten Kettner, I edited the question to show the correct desired results

Comment: Your idea what `GROUP BY` does is wrong by the way. It does get you one record per group (in your example `from_user_id, to_user_id`). It does not, however, magically choose the records/values you want for you. In `SELECT text, from_user_id, to_user_id, created`, you say you want to select a `text` for the group. But there are many. The DBMS is free to choose one and will arbitrarily do so. So for 13/14 you may get " Hi there!" or "Fine, thanks for asking. How are you?"; the DBMS is free to pick one. If you want a specific one, you need an aggregation function (`MAX`, `MIN` or the like).

Comment: What you would need, however, is the text for the `max(created)` - an aggregation function that MySQL does not provide. (Oracle for instance does with `KEEP LAST`, but MySQL does not have such a function.) `ORDER BY created DESC` is executed at last, i.e. *after* `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One method of doing what you want uses a correlated subquery, to find the minimum created date/time for a matching conversation:

```
SELECT m.*
FROM message m
WHERE 13 in (from_user_id, to_user_id) AND
      m.created = (SELECT MAX(m2.created)
                   FROM message m2
                   WHERE (m2.from_user_id = m.from_user_id AND m2.to_user_id = m.to_user_id) OR
                         (m2.from_user_id = m.to_user_id AND m2.to_user_id = m.from_user_id) 
                  )
ORDER BY m.created DESC
```

Comment: shouldn't it be MAX() since OP wants the latest message?

Comment: Yes, `MAX()` should be used, but to be fair I provided the wrong desired result in the question.

Answer (score 2):

The last conversations with #13? In a more up-to-date DBMS you'd use `row_number()` to find these. In MySQL you can use `not exists`, to make sure that there is no later post for the conversation partners. You find the partner's number easily with `from_user_id + to_user_id - 13` by the way. (And when comparing two records, you can just use `from_user_id + to_user_id`.)

```
select text, from_user_id, to_user_id, created
from message m1
where 13 in (from_user_id, to_user_id)
and not exists
(
  select *
  from message m2
  where 13 in (m2.from_user_id, m2.to_user_id)
  and m2.from_user_id + m2.to_user_id = m1.from_user_id + m1.to_user_id
  and m2.created > m1.created
);
```

Comment: You **CAN'T** compare id sums, `13 + 5 = 8 + 10` but are different conversations

Comment: @Juan Carlos Oropeza: You are missing the `WHERE` clause. Your second pair doesn't contain a 13 and would hence not be selected.

Answer (score 0):

I use `GREATEST` and `LEAST` to create a grp for each conversation. Then sort for that grp and assign a row number based on the time.

[**SQL DEMO**](http://rextester.com/YHBUO18991)

```
SELECT *
FROM (
        SELECT LEAST(`from_user_id`, `to_user_id`) as L,
               GREATEST(`from_user_id`, `to_user_id`) as G,
               `text`,
               CONCAT (LEAST(`from_user_id`, `to_user_id`), '-', GREATEST(`from_user_id`, `to_user_id`)) as grp,
               @rn := if(@grp = CONCAT(LEAST(`from_user_id`, `to_user_id`), '-', GREATEST(`from_user_id`, `to_user_id`)),
                         @rn + 1,
                         if(@grp := CONCAT(LEAST(`from_user_id`, `to_user_id`), '-', GREATEST(`from_user_id`, `to_user_id`)), 1, 1)
                         ) as rn,
               `time`
        FROM Table1
        CROSS JOIN (SELECT @rn := 0, @grp := '') as var
        ORDER BY LEAST(`from_user_id`, `to_user_id`),
                 GREATEST(`from_user_id`, `to_user_id`),
                 `time` DESC
     ) T
WHERE rn = 1;
```

**OUTPUT** 
[image]

**EDIT:** at the end you need to filter the 13 from the conversation.

```
WHERE rn = 1
  AND 13 IN (`L`, `G`);
```