# how to sort users based on the latest chats

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i have a chat website and i want the user to have a list available of users sorted by who they last chatted with(like whatsapp).
how do i do this?
i tried many stack overflow answers but none of them worked for me so far.
when using the code i use now the names of the users repeat for every message that exists.
this query isn't working: "SELECT * FROM dms WHERE sentTo = ".$_SESSION['id']." or sentBy = ".$_SESSION['id'].";"
this is what my database looks like:
[image]

this is my code:

```
<?php
                $sql = "SELECT * FROM dms WHERE sentTo = ".$_SESSION['id']." or sentBy = ".$_SESSION['id'].";";
                $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
                if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
                    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                        $sql2 = "SELECT id, username FROM users WHERE id = ".$row['sentTo'].";";
                        $result2 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql2);
                        if (mysqli_num_rows($result2) > 0) {
                            while ($row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2)) {
                                echo "<a href='dms.php?talkingTo=".$row2['id']."'>".$row2['username']."</a>";
                            }
                        }else{
                            echo "<p>It's empty</p>";
                        }
                    }
                }else{
                    echo "<p>It's empty</p>";
                }
            ?>
```

Comment: @KenLee then it would sort the messages when i need to sort the users based on the messages

Comment: @KenLee when i do that the list just flips, it re orders. but not based on who was last sent a message.

Comment: @KenLee yes that is what in trying to do. i do not understand how ordering the date in descending order would help.

Comment: **Hint:** Think on how whatsapp (or similar) does it - it is normal that the user record will have a data field storing the "last datetime" of activities

Comment: @KenLee by sorting the users based on the last sent message?

Comment: Yes, that's one of the methods.

Comment: @KenLee yes, i could store it but i dont know how with the way my database was made and there must be another way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using this query:

```
"SELECT * FROM dms WHERE sentTo = ".$_SESSION['id']." or sentBy = ".$_SESSION['id'].";
```

- What you are currently doing is querying for all available DMs sent to or from the current user(in session). All DMs mean duplicate entries for the same conversation aka chat
- But what you want to achieve is to list out all unique 'chats' of this user PLUS sort this list based on latest activity on each chat

Correct me if I am wrong.

What you need to do is group the chats based on the similarity of the combination of the `sentBy` and `sentTo` columns. This can never be similar if you want to skip duplicates. In addition, you want to order the chats based on the `date` column in descending.

From an [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46007897/7368896) to a *mostly* similar question I got "one method of doing what you want that uses a correlated subquery, to find the minimum created date/time for a matching conversation".

It also sorts the results based on the date.

So making these corrections and customizing the query from the older question to your context - the above query you used should be changed to(Replace `where 1` by concatenating the id from session: $_SESSION['id']):

```
SELECT m.*
FROM dms m
WHERE 1 in (sentBy, sentTo) AND
      m.date = (SELECT MAX(m2.date)
                   FROM dms m2
                   WHERE (m2.sentBy = m.sentBy AND m2.sentTo = m.sentTo) OR
                         (m2.sentBy = m.sentTo AND m2.sentTo = m.sentBy) 
                  )
ORDER BY m.date DESC
```

I run this query on an identical dataset of your dms table and got 2 unique results.

One additional thing you may need to check is the link you want to generate by using the anchor:

```
echo "<a href='dms.php?talkingTo=".$row2['id']."'>".$row2['username']."</a>";
```

This is echoing out the `id` of the current user. I think you were supposed to echo out the `id` of the who they are chatting to? If so you need to run the query to get who it is sent from instead.

Hope this helps.

Comment: it's not working for me so im probably still doing something wrong, but ill accept the answer because its the most helpful. thank you so much!
edit: its working now idk how thank you again, so much!

Answer (score 0):

We need to group the dms records based on who the chat is with, knowing that I (id 1) am either the sender or recipient.

If it is sentTo 1 (Me) and sentBy 2 (You)
then it is sentBy we are interested in.
Conversely, if it is sentTo 2 (You) and sentBy 1 (Me)
then it is sentTo we are interested in.

Putting this into SQL we have -

```
IF(sentTo = 1, sentBy, sentTo)
```

We can now use this in our query of the dms table to group by who we are interacting with and use MAX to find the most recent interaction -

```
SELECT IF(sentTo = 1, sentBy, sentTo) chatWith, MAX(date) mostRecent
FROM dms
WHERE sentTo = 1 OR sentBy = 1
GROUP BY chatWith
```

In your code you are running an additional query per row returned by the first query. This is not necessary as we can join to the users table -

```
SELECT u.id, u.username, t.mostRecent
FROM (
    SELECT IF(sentTo = 1, sentBy, sentTo) chatWith, MAX(date) mostRecent
    FROM dms
    WHERE sentTo = 1 OR sentBy = 1
    GROUP BY chatWith
) t
JOIN users u ON t.chatWith = u.id
ORDER BY t.mostRecent DESC
```

Putting all of this into your code we end up with -

```php
<?php

$sql = "
    SELECT u.id, u.username, t.mostRecent
    FROM (
        SELECT IF(sentTo = {$_SESSION['id']}, sentBy, sentTo) chatWith, MAX(date) mostRecent
        FROM dms
        WHERE sentTo = {$_SESSION['id']} OR sentBy = {$_SESSION['id']}
        GROUP BY chatWith
    ) t
    JOIN users u ON t.chatWith = u.id
    ORDER BY t.mostRecent DESC";

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo "<a href='dms.php?talkingTo={$row['id']}'>{$row['username']}</a><br>";
    }
} else {
    echo "<p>It's empty</p>";
}
```

I have tested this with 1M randomly (ish) generated rows and it returns consistently in less than 0.02s on my local dev machine.

**UPDATE** - some test results

EXPLAIN output for each of the three queries with a test dataset of 10k rows - users.id between 1 and 500 and date between 2021-01-01 and current.

```
/* groupwise max */
EXPLAIN
SELECT u.id, u.username, t.mostRecent
FROM (
    SELECT IF(sentTo = 1, sentBy, sentTo) chatWith, MAX(date) mostRecent
    FROM dms
    WHERE sentTo = 1 OR sentBy = 1
    GROUP BY chatWith
) t
JOIN users u ON t.chatWith = u.id
ORDER BY t.mostRecent DESC;

# Serverside execution time: 0.001s
# Rows examined: 66
# Rows returned: 22
```

| id | select_type | table | partitions | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | filtered | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | PRIMARY |  |  | ALL |  |  |  |  | 43 | 100.00 | Using filesort |
| 1 | PRIMARY | u |  | eq_ref | PRIMARY | PRIMARY | 2 | t.chatWith | 1 | 100.00 | Using where |
| 2 | DERIVED | dms |  | index_merge | IDX_from,IDX_to,IDX_from_to,IDX_to_from | IDX_to,IDX_from | 4,4 |  | 43 | 100.00 | Using union(IDX_to,IDX_from); Using where; Using temporary |

```
/* correlated subquery 1 */
EXPLAIN
SELECT m.*
FROM dms m
WHERE 1 in (sentBy, sentTo) AND
      m.date = (SELECT MAX(m2.date)
                   FROM dms m2
                   WHERE (m2.sentBy = m.sentBy AND m2.sentTo = m.sentTo) OR
                         (m2.sentBy = m.sentTo AND m2.sentTo = m.sentBy) 
                  )
ORDER BY m.date DESC;

# Serverside execution time: 0.122s
# Rows examined: 440022
# Rows returned: 22
```

| id | select_type | table | partitions | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | filtered | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | PRIMARY | m |  | ALL |  |  |  |  | 9847 | 100.00 | Using where; Using filesort |
| 2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | m2 |  | ALL | IDX_from,IDX_to,IDX_from_to,IDX_to_from |  |  |  | 9847 | 1.99 | Range checked for each record (index map: 0x1E) |

```
/* correlated subquery 2 */
EXPLAIN
SELECT m.*
FROM dms m
WHERE (sentTo = 1 OR sentBy = 1) AND
      m.date = (SELECT MAX(m2.date)
                   FROM dms m2
                   WHERE (m2.sentBy = m.sentBy AND m2.sentTo = m.sentTo) OR
                         (m2.sentBy = m.sentTo AND m2.sentTo = m.sentBy) 
                  )
ORDER BY m.date DESC;

# Serverside execution time: 0.122s
# Rows examined: 430022
# Rows returned: 22
```

| id | select_type | table | partitions | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | filtered | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | PRIMARY | m |  | index_merge | IDX_from,IDX_to,IDX_from_to,IDX_to_from | IDX_to,IDX_from | 4,4 |  | 43 | 100.00 | Using union(IDX_to,IDX_from); Using where; Using filesort |
| 2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | m2 |  | ALL | IDX_from,IDX_to,IDX_from_to,IDX_to_from |  |  |  | 9847 | 1.99 | Range checked for each record (index map: 0x1E) |

**Summary of performance observations based on 10k, 100k & 1M datasets**

| 10k | Groupwise max | Correlated subquery 1 | Correlated subquery 2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Serverside execution time (s) | 0.001 | 0.119 | 0.115 |
| Rows examined | 63 | 420,021 | 410,021 |
| Rows returned | 21 | 21 | 21 |

| 100k | Groupwise max | Correlated subquery 1 | Correlated subquery 2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Serverside execution time (s) | 0.003 | 11 | 10 |
| Rows examined | 597 | 38,900,199 | 38,800,199 |
| Rows returned | 199 | 199 | 199 |

| 1M | Groupwise max | Correlated subquery 1 | Correlated subquery 2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Serverside execution time (s) | 0.018 | 1072 | 1046 |
| Rows examined | 1,497 | 3,999,000,499 | 3,998,000,499 |
| Rows returned | 499 | 499 | 499 |